# JavaScript issue with NaN

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a JavaScript game an I've got a problem with two properties of one of my objects. 
The properties x and y are NaN, but I can't understand why. Now I post the code:

```
var canvas;
var ctx;
var canvasH = 480;
var canvasW = 960;

window.onload = function () {
canvas  = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx     = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width  = canvasW;
canvas.height = canvasH;

drawCanvas();
}
```

The function drawCanvas() :

```
function drawCanvas () {

ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasW, canvasH);
}
```

And here the constructor for my object:

```
function SpaceCraft () {

var obj = this;

this.texture = new Image();
this.texture.src = "img/spacecraft.png";
this.texture.onload = function () {
    obj.w = this.width;
    obj.h = this.height;
}

this.x = canvasW / 2 - obj.w / 2; //PROBLEM IS NaN
this.y = canvasH - obj.h;         //PROBLEM IS NaN

//Methods

//Draw

this.draw = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(this.texture, this.x, this.y);
}
}
```

Thank you for your help!


Sorry but I wrote a new post because no-one answer the old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`obj.w` and `obj.h` are unset at the time you use them.

Your code:

```
this.texture = new Image();
this.texture.src = "img/spacecraft.png";
this.texture.onload = function () {
    obj.w = this.width;
    obj.h = this.height;
}

// the following lines won't get executed after the onload event
// they will be executed immediately after the assignment of the onload event 
this.x = canvasW / 2 - obj.w / 2; //PROBLEM IS NaN
this.y = canvasH - obj.h;         //PROBLEM IS NaN
```

`obj.w` and `obj.h` will get assigned after the texture has been loaded, however, you immediately use them in the last two lines from the excerpt above.

You have to move those lines into the callback function `.onload`, so you can ensure the existence of the variables width and height.

Also, there is one pitfall concerning `this` – the context. `this` in the `onload` callback function does not refer to an instance of *Spacecraft*.
Since you already have a variable `obj` which refers to your *Spacecraft* instance, just use it:

```
this.texture = new Image();
this.texture.src = "img/spacecraft.png";

this.texture.onload = function () {
    obj.w = this.width;
    obj.h = this.height;
    obj.x = canvasW / 2 - obj.w / 2; //PROBLEM IS NaN
    obj.y = canvasH - obj.h;         //PROBLEM IS NaN  
}
```

---

Another option is to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the callback function to a specific context.

Note that you have to replace `this.width/height` by `this.texture.width/height` since `this` doesn't refer to the *Image* object anymore!

```
this.texture = new Image();
this.texture.src = "img/spacecraft.png";

this.texture.onload = (function () {
    // obj = this due to the use of bind()

    this.w = this.texture.width;
    this.h = this.texture.height;
    this.x = canvasW / 2 - this.w / 2; //PROBLEM IS NaN
    this.y = canvasH - this.h;         //PROBLEM IS NaN  
}).bind(this);
```

Comment: Note that `$this == obj`

Comment: @user3457128 Please see my update. I included some wrong code. You cannot use `this.width` in the callback function since `this` doesn't refer to the *Image* object anymore.